# Postgresql Sum statistics by month for a single year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in the database:

| item_id, integer | item_name, character varying | price, double precision | user_id, integer | category_id, integer | date, date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pizza | 2.99 | 1 | 2 | '2020-01-01' |
| 2 | Cinema | 5 | 1 | 3 | '2020-01-01' |
| 3 | Cheeseburger | 4.99 | 1 | 2 | '2020-01-01' |
| 4 | Rental | 100 | 1 | 1 | '2020-01-01' |

Now I want to get the statistics for the total price for each month in a year. It should include all items as well as a single category both for all the time and specified time period. For example, using this

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH from date),COALESCE(SUM(price), 0) 
FROM item_table
WHERE user_id = 1 AND category_id = 3 AND date BETWEEN '2020-01-01'AND '2021-01-01'
GROUP By date_part
ORDER BY date_part;
```

I expect to obtain this:

| date_part | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| ... | ... |
| 12 | 0 |

However, I get this:

| date_part | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |

**1)** How can I get zero value for a case when no items for a specified category are found? (now it just skips the month) 
**2)** The above example gives the statistics for the selected category within some time period.  For all my purposes I need to write 3 more queries (select for all time and all categories/ all the time single category/ single year all categories). Is there a unique query for all these cases? (when some parameters like category_id or date are *null* )

Comment: Welcome to the SO community, The community will help you with your issues, but in return there are certain expectations; see [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [ask]. In particular you need to provide table definitions, sample data, and expected results of that data - all as text - **no images**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the "empty" months by doing a right join against a table that contains the month numbers and moving the `WHERE` criteria into the `JOIN` criteria:

```sql
-- Create a temporary "table" for month numbers
WITH months AS (SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 12) AS t(n))

SELECT months.n as date_part, COALESCE(SUM(price), 0) AS total
FROM item_table
RIGHT JOIN months ON EXTRACT(MONTH from date) = months.n
  AND user_id = 1 AND category_id = 3 AND "date" BETWEEN '2020-01-01'AND '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY months.n
ORDER By months.n;
```

I'm not quite sure what you want from your second part, but you could take a look at [Grouping Sets, Cube and Rollup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS).